# If columns match, take value from another column and assign it to a new variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-management

I have a data set that contains a group an id variable and a pair id variable. Each observation is paired with another observation. I want to create a new variable that takes the id variable of its pair-partner and assign it as a new 'partner' variable.

Below I have an example data:

```
id <- 1:10
pair_id <- rep(1:5,2)

df <- cbind(id, pair_id)

> df
      id pair_id
 [1,]  1       1
 [2,]  2       2
 [3,]  3       3
 [4,]  4       4
 [5,]  5       5
 [6,]  6       1
 [7,]  7       2
 [8,]  8       3
 [9,]  9       4
[10,] 10       5
```

As I said above, I want to add a variable indicating on each `id` partner's `id`, where the partnership is identified with the `pair_id`. As an example, observations with `id == 1` has `pair_id == 1`, which makes it partner to be the observation with `id == 6`, since they share  `pair_id`.

So the end result should look like this:

```
     id pair_id partner_id
 [1,]  1       1          6
 [2,]  2       2          7
 [3,]  3       3          8
 [4,]  4       4          9
 [5,]  5       5         10
 [6,]  6       1          1
 [7,]  7       2          2
 [8,]  8       3          3
 [9,]  9       4          4
[10,] 10       5          5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the `id` values for each `pair_id` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(pair_id) %>% mutate(partner_id = rev(id))

#      id pair_id partner_id
#   <int>   <int>      <int>
# 1     1       1          6
# 2     2       2          7
# 3     3       3          8
# 4     4       4          9
# 5     5       5         10
# 6     6       1          1
# 7     7       2          2
# 8     8       3          3
# 9     9       4          4
#10    10       5          5
```

The equivalent in base R :

```
df$partner_id <- with(df, ave(id, pair_id, FUN = rev))
```

and in `data.table` is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, partner_id := rev(id), pair_id]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(id, pair_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not think the solution would be that 'simple'.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
 library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(pair_id) %>%
      mutate(partner_id = id[n():1])
```